# Bootstrap anchor element and button with no space between

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap 3 and I have a line of buttons. One of them is a `<a>` button, or: `<a class='btn btn-default' role='button'>Button here</a>`; the rest are `<button>` elements with the same classes.

I was expecting to have them all correctly aligned and spaced, as seen in [Bootstrap's examples](http://getbootstrap.com/css/?#buttons-tags), however, the result was this:

[image: No space between anchor and button]

As you can see, the first button, the one specified as `<a>` doesn't have the right margin with the next button. What can be causing this?

Here's my HTML:

```
<a class="btn btn-default" role="button">
   <i class="fa fa-download" aria-hidden="true"></i> Download Image
</a>
<button class="btn btn-default">
   <i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> Edit Title
</button>
<button class="btn btn-default">Export</button>
<button class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
```

Comment: Do you have any extra CSS for anchor tags that may be affecting the spacing?

Comment: No, not for anchor tags directly, at least... and according to the inspector, it seems there's nothing affecting that

Answer (score 0):

The `anchor` tags and `button`s are correctly spaced because they are `inline-block`- not sure how there is no spacing between the `a` and the `button` you got over there.

Try `float`ing them and then you can remove the `space` between them if you want to- and set the required margin if needed.

They must be correctly aligned and spaced by default- see below snippet:

```css
a.btn, button.btn {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<body>
<a class="btn btn-default" role="button">
   <i class="fa fa-download" aria-hidden="true"></i> Download Image
</a>
<button class="btn btn-default">
   <i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> Edit Title
</button>
<button class="btn btn-default">Export</button>
<button class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
  </body>
```

See what happens when we **float** them:

```css
a.btn, button.btn {
  margin: 0;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<body>
<a class="btn btn-default" role="button">
   <i class="fa fa-download" aria-hidden="true"></i> Download Image
</a>
<button class="btn btn-default">
   <i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> Edit Title
</button>
<button class="btn btn-default">Export</button>
<button class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
  </body>
```

Comment: It does seem to work, if I specify a margin like 5px. But I wanted to used the predefined margins, isn't it possible?

Comment: check the updated answer... by default, it will have a predefined margin

Comment: @pavlag found the issue?

Comment: Well, it is working here.. but not in my project... They're inside a `<div>` with `position: relative;`, but I don't think that's the problem, since if I turn it off all remains the same

Comment: well, it must be working like its here... meanwhile don't know why or who down voted me :(

Comment: I'll try to mess around a bit with my code, again... As for the down vote, it wasn't me!

Comment: @pavlag you found the issue? just curious

Comment: no. No idea. Probably gonna do what you recommended